# Ошибка в телеграм боте

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Делаю своего первого бота, прописал админс чтобы бот работал с админом - картинки, текст, описание.
После запуска бота все окей но после ввода любой команды хоть /start выдает ошибку, наверное стоит упомянуть что запускаю бота через bat файл. Так же проблема началась после ввода этого кода, (dispatcher импортировал)  -

```py
def register_handlers_admin(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, commands=['Загрузить'], state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_photo, content_types=['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_name, state=FSMAdmin.name)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_description, state=FSMAdmin.description)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_price, state=FSMAdmin.price)
```

Не понимаю почему обращается к Dispatcher, работал нормально. Заранее спс, вылетает такая ошибка в консоли -

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\99555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("get_state() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\99555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\filters\builtin.py", line 543, in check
```

Comment: Дайте весь код, из этого огрызка ничего не понятно

Comment: А также весь текст исключения